# Nonsingular gaussian measures

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, normal-distribution

Currently I'm trying to prove that if we assume that if $N(m_{1},Q_{1})$ and $N(m_{2},Q_{2})$ are nonsingular , and their shifts are nonsingular $N(0,Q_{1})$ and $N(m_{2}-m_{1},Q_{2})$  , as well as their symmetric images $N(0,Q_{1})$ and $N(m_{1}-m_{2},Q_{2})$ then

$N(0,2Q_{1})=N(0,Q_{1})*N(0,Q_{1})$ and
$N(0,2Q_{2})=N(m_{2}-m_{1},Q_{2})*N(m_{1}-m_{2},Q_{2})$ are nonsingular.

Thank you in advance.